# Missing Witness field in p2wpkh decoded tx hex

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness, bitcoinjs, p2wpkh, witness-data

I have placed together a raw tx hex but when it's unable to be broadcasted as I keep getting an error below

```
sendrawtransaction RPC error: {"code":-25,"message":"bad-txns-inputs-missingorspent"}
```

I then decoded the tx hex using https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/decodetx/ to see that I seem to be missing the Witness field as I am using native segwit addresses:

```
{
    "addresses": [
        "bc1qj3rjxzhlqm6fqesd5fwphjnf457zkww3s5qrv5",
        "bc1qjp3cch0hdvdr0hy99cs76kl9kekmuxv3k9nr6l"
    ],
    "block_height": -1,
    "block_index": -1,
    "confirmations": 0,
    "double_spend": false,
    "fees": 200,
    "hash": "88420211f5ea53174fc6a708c00ca2e840d687591573d0ecd2464fae20d139a7",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "addresses": [
                "bc1qj3rjxzhlqm6fqesd5fwphjnf457zkww3s5qrv5"
            ],
            "age": 696993,
            "output_index": 0,
            "output_value": 60200,
            "prev_hash": "74e24a2d50ba64abc099126c1c208b5f7156e3ad515b86f3edcca3f3d4291f66",
            "script": "4730440220516e15b6354f17e3f02711107624005e6ccd26cf61ef21b35e91315dfbd33e9f022049dadb73ca3e814de9da0b35ff20a8ca82147dda138ede948ccac5621a5bc1bb01210384485d43e938f8c68c4ac903d4d5a97fe842f66c12b860d8d2e1242d2b01fc1f",
            "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash",
            "sequence": 4294967295
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "addresses": [
                "bc1qjp3cch0hdvdr0hy99cs76kl9kekmuxv3k9nr6l"
            ],
            "script": "001490638c5df76b1a37dc852e21ed5be5b66dbe1991",
            "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash",
            "value": 60000
        }
    ],
    "preference": "low",
    "received": "2021-09-05T10:17:14.395062568Z",
    "relayed_by": "3.82.154.159",
    "size": 188,
    "total": 60000,
    "ver": 2,
    "vin_sz": 1,
    "vout_sz": 1,
    "vsize": 188
}
```

I then thought perhaps I didn't add a `scriptPubKey` into the `addInput` but this code didn't seem to work for me:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const bitcoin = require("bitcoinjs-lib")
const url = "https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/"
let MAINNET = bitcoin.networks.bitcoin
pubAdd = "bc1qj3rjxzhlqm6fqesd5fwphjnf457zkww3s5qrv5"

let txb = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder(MAINNET)
var txid = null
var outn = 0
var transactionhex = ""

async function getPubAddInfo() {
  const response = await fetch(url + pubAdd)
  const data = await response.json()

  txid = data["txs"][0]["hash"]
  outn = data["txs"][0]["out"][0]["n"]
}

async function getTXHash() {
  await getPubAddInfo()

  let WIF = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  let keypairSpend = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF(WIF, MAINNET)

  var scriptPubkey = bitcoin.script.witnessPubKeyHash.output.encode(bitcoin.crypto.hash160(keypairSpend.getPublicKeyBuffer()))

  txb.addInput(txid, outn, null, scriptPubkey)

  txb.addOutput("bc1qjp3cch0hdvdr0hy99cs76kl9kekmuxv3k9nr6l", 60000)

  txb.sign(0, keypairSpend, null, null, 60200)

  let tx = txb.build()
  transactionhex = tx.toHex()
  console.log(transactionhex)
}

getTXHash()
```

At the moment I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'output' of undefined` on the line where i create `var scriptPubKey`.

Any suggestions as to how I can add the Witness field into the tx? Is it because I am improperly adding the scriptPubKey? I am using bitcoinjs 5.2.0

Comment: Are you actually signing the transaction?

Comment: @PieterWuille Yes, I have it like this: 

`let WIF = "xxxxxxxxx"` , `let keypairSpend = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF(WIF, MAINNET)` , `txb.sign(0, keypairSpend, null, null, 60200)`

Comment: @PieterWuille I have updated my original question above to show you the full code I am using.

Answer (score 0):

How are you signing it? Also what version of bitcoinjs are you using? Looks like an older one (v3.3?)prior to PSBTs. It might be a little different depending on version. Spending from segwit addresses (p2sh or native) you must specify **inputvalue**, this is the full value of the unspent output being spent.

`txb.sign(0, keypairSpend, null, null, inputvalue);`

As of v.4.03 for an example spending from p2wpkh with the latest transaction builder see their github reference docs at https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/integration/transactions.spec.ts#L11

Comment: I have updated my original question to show you the full code I am using. I am also using bitcoinjs v5.2.0